# How to pivot multiple column based on a single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Hi I have table which has multiple columns.
I would like to pivot column x, y ,z etc for column name 'Period' for period between 1-12.

I have written this

```
pivot(
  Sum([x]
  For [Period] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
   ) as Pv1
```

Which only gives me for one column.

if I wanted for more than one column. How would i approach it?

Answer (score 1):

Use multi pivot in this case

```
pivot(
  Sum([x]
  For [Period] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
   ) as Pv1
,
pivot(
  Sum([y]
  For [Period] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
   ) as Pv2
,
pivot(
  Sum([z]
  For [Period] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
   ) as Pv3
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and desired result, that can speak more than words.